# How can I research an old Nazi ring that grandfather brought back from war?

Tags: nazi-germany, identification

My grandfather brought back a ring, it has the swastika on it. How can I find out more about it and the value it? I have asked several people and gone to many pawnshops, I have no idea where else to go.

Comment: It would help if you could supply an image of the ring or, at least, a more comprehensive description. Given that you have little information about it (and therefore can't attribute prior ownership), it's unlikely to have much value. Just about every soldier that served in Germany immediately after the war came home with a set of Nazi memorabilia.

Answer (score 1):

It might be

- simply a piece of jewelry decorated with the swastika, then it has little or no value beyond the metal it is made from;
- a Totenkopfring like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Ehrenring), which might have collector's value.